# I got an error while tried to send an email in python

Tags: python, gmail

This is the code:

```
import smtplib

sender = "" #sender email here
receiver = "" #reciver email here
password = input(str("Password: "))
message = "This email sent using python."

server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
server.starttls()
server.login(sender, password)
print("Login sucsess.")
server.sendmail(sender, receiver, message)
print("Email sent.")
```

But I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\36704\Desktop\email_practice.py", line 12, in <module>
    server.sendmail(sender, receiver, message)
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\smtplib.py", line 859, in sendmail
    msg = _fix_eols(msg).encode('ascii')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xf3' in position 13: ordinal not in range(128)
```

It just doesn't work. What should I do?

Comment: text that you try to send contains signs that `sendmail` con't endode

Comment: The message you are sending will not raise the error given. The 14. character in your message is `n` but the error days says it is somethings else.

Comment: You can ignore any invalid characters (in this case `\xf3`) by simply encoding your message as follow: `message = message.encode("ascii", errors="ignore")`

Comment: Thank you guys! Especially to @RezaBehzadpour!